# How can I reset my device without losing images on it?

Tags: factory-reset, images

I know I can backup and restore. But I just don't want the images to be deleted (either phone memory or sd card). Meaning, have the folder of the images remain, so that Gallery can read all the images from it after reset.

I want to reset because after an upgrade to Lollipop, com.android.phone doesn't work. So I tried several options, but could not solve this, so now I'm looking to reset

Comment: Depending on the device and ROM: either all data stored on your "media storage" (i.e. internal and external SD card) stays untouched, or all storage will be pruned. You can play Russian Roulette trying to find out. But the safer way is to backup at least internal storage/SDCard, and take the external SDCard out. B'Hazlacha :)

Answer (score -1):

Factory reset does NOT erase any user data. It just erases system/data/data folder and cache. This is the reason why sometimes problems doesn't get fix after all: Because is not so low level as we'd like.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. I believe a factory reset **WILL** erase user data on the device itself. It won't affect the SD card though. If there are files/photos/etc. stored on the device itself these will be lost when doing a factory reset.

Comment: @bmdixon You're wrong. The internal storage has, let's say, two parts: The one needed for the system and the _usable_ by the user. Last one, _usable_ is treated by Android as an SD too, exactly as it does with the physical removable SD card. Factory reset only erases the first one, and not absolutely, because in that case you'd get no operative system. It just erases data and cache folders.

Comment: The [tag:factory-reset] tag wiki and many other questions on this site appear to be saying that a factory reset will wipe user data. If there is a /internalsd partition then this won't be wiped but /data is wiped AFAIK. Which on a device such like a Nexus 5 would result in all user data being deleted.

Comment: By data you must understand applications and its corresponding files like Shared Preferences, Databases and Cache. And NOT user files like Photos or Videos stored on DCIM folder, as sample. Even Whatsapp backups will resist a Factory Reset. You really should try it first before discussing.

Comment: I factory reset my Nexus 4 before selling it. **ALL** user data (apps, settings, photos, videos etc) was deleted. I was simply trying to highlight a potential issue with your answer. As Izzy said in his comment on the question it may vary between devices so you may be correct for non Nexus devices. I was simply trying to highlight a potential issue with your answer, I'm not going to argue any further...